# 404 error in the Front End of a Magento extension

Tags: magento, nginx, http-status-code-404, frontend, magento-1.9

I installed manually a Magento extension called [Featured products by Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/featured-products-on-magento-frontpage/). 
When I did it, I could configure it as usual. But when I activated it, I should be able to see the featured products frontend with the url */featured-products*. Instead of that, I get a **404 error**.

When I debug it to see when the 404 error was raised, I have the surprise to see that Magento doesn't even go in the *validateControllerClassName*.

I'm new in Magento so, I've maybe not understand all the mechanism of it.

I'm on that bug for 1 day.

So if you have an idea of the issue, go on! I'm desperate!

*Techs : Magento 1.9, Nginx server*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the basic approach of reindexing and flushing cache?
System->Cache Management (Flush magento cache) and System-> Index Management
Also try restarting PHP5-fpm just in case.

Comment: I've done that but nothing change. The thing is that I've done the same install on another website with the same configuration and it's work.

Comment: If you try to call the block on some own page by adding:  
`{{block type="featuredproducts/listing"}}` 
then does it show the featured products?